# C++ big header files (4.5MB or more) with huge static arrays

Tags: c++, performance, android-ndk

I have three big header files (4.5MB and more), with huge static arrays inside.

I need to add these header files to a C++ Android native code project and I don't know if this is the right way.

I'm thinking that these are big files and contains big arrays. I don't know if they will generate a big lib.so and if arrays will consume a lot of RAM.

For example one array contains 4,032 float elements, and other array contains 8,056 int elements.

What do you think?

Thanks.

Comment: You are not compiling this on a phone.  48,352 bytes isn't much.

Comment: Seems like you actually need a mesh loader, instead of hardcoding the geometry in your shared library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would **strongly** advise against defining static arrays (i.e., actually specifying `static int foo[8056]`) in header files. It's much better to declare them as `extern` in the header file, and define them in a single C or C++ source file.

Every source file in which those headers are included (even indirectly) will generate its own definition for those static arrays. There's no guarantee that the compiler/linker will optimize them into a single definition, even in source files where they're unused. In fact, in many cases the compiler *cannot* optimize them away. This could result in your static data consuming a lot of disk space, and possibly runtime memory as well.

I can't say much about the other 4.4+ MB of your header files, since I don't know what's in them.

Comment: A lot of text. Three or four static arrays with a lot of numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the header has a lot of "fluff" compared to the compiled down version. So your static arrays won't be *that* big...

(4,032+8,056)*4 = 48,352

But I would usually go for either building that data at runtime or storing it in some sort of data file. In some cases the data can be generated faster than it is read (such as lists of primes). It depends on the data and it's usage.

Comment: The data a float numbers. They are vertices for rendering a model with OpenGL ES 2.0.